# c++ process always on foreground in window OS

Tags: c++, c, windows

I have a c++ process, I want that process should always remain on foreground, kindly guide me how can I make it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible since user always has an option to switch to another application. This is by design.

Good link from [Billy ONeal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82320):

> [How do I create a window that is never covered by any other windows, not even other topmost windows?](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/07/426294.aspx)
>
> Imagine if this were possible and imagine if two programs did this. Program A creates a window that is "super-topmost" and so does Program B. Now the user drags the two windows so that they overlap. What happens? You've created yourself a logical impossibility. One of those two windows must be above the other, contradicting the imaginary "super-topmost" feature.

Comment: *Foreground* is not the same as *Always on top*.

Comment: +1. @Arman: You may wish to read this: http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2009/03/18/9485229.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Set the window as topmost by using the Win32 API [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545(VS.85).aspx), with a value of `HWND_TOPMOST` for the `hWndInsertAfter` parameter.  You can in addition use [BringWindowToTop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632673(VS.85).aspx) to bring the window to the top of the z-order.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are wanting to know how to turn a Windows PC into a Kiosk application.

Setting up a Kiosk requires [replacing the windows shell](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/WindowsXP/AdminTips/IEandExplorer/KioskComputers.html). Once this is done you usually have no further issues as, unless you provide the facility to launch other applications, you are the only one running.
Using the Group Policy Editor also can help lock down a PC for use as a Kiosk.
Kiosk's are also vulnerable if a keyboard is available or can be added (providing a usb interface for example means ppl can plug a keyboard in), in which case you need to ensure that ctl-alt-delete goes to your own task manager, not the system one, as the systems task manager can be used to launch arbitrary applications.